# python - find positive/negative/positive pattern in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Does `numpy` have an easy way to determine if an array has a pattern that looks like this: (positives numbers followed by negative numbers followed by positive numbers)?

Example:

```
myArray = np.array([5, 5, 3, 6, -2, -5, 4, 9])
myArray2 = np.array([5, 5, 3, 6, 8, 4, -5, -8])

if foundPatern(myArray):  # True
if foundPatern(myArray2): # False
```

Comment: A pure numpy solution:
`check = np.all((x[np.hstack((True,np.diff(x>=0)))]>=0)==[True,False,True])` where `x` is your array. I keep only the value where the sign change and check if the sign is indeed `Positive Negative Positive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a `numpy` built-in to convert each element of an array to 1, 0, -1 based on the sign. You could easily use `itertools.groupby` for this task after converting the sign:

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np


def foundPattern(lst):
    g = list(groupby(np.sign(lst)))
    return (len(g)==3 and g[0][0]==1.0)
```

This works as follows:

1. The items of your array are grouped based on their sign (+ or -)
2. If exactly 3 groups exist and the first one is a group of positives, you return `True`; in all other cases you return `False`

Note that you have not specified how edge cases are to be treated (e.g., 0 in the array) so I will not attempt to handle them in any way. Be mindful however that they do exist. Another example of an edge case could be `NaN`.

Comment: This is perfect! Didn't know of itertools until now. Thanks for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: @FarhanAhmad then you better have a look because `itertools` is an extremely useful library. Cheers.

Comment: There is a numpy built-in for this: `np.sign`. You can modify the first line of the function to: `g = list(groupby(np.sign(lst)))`

Comment: @SNygard thats even better! Feel free to edit, I am away from the pc atm